# Is it mandatory to create a EC2 instance to connect document DB from Mongo compass?

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I have been trying to figure out what exactly is the issue connecting document DB cluster from mongo compass or studio 3T. I use following connection string but it doesn't work. Some says, we need to connect through EC2. But why on earth I have to create an EC2 instance to connect to document DB. I simply created a Document DB cluster thinking that it will work on its own.

```
mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?tls=true&ssl_ca_certs=certfile&retryWrites=false
```

This is what is the security group inbound rules:
[image]

Comment: Is your document db accessible from internet ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How to make sure whether it is accessible ?

Comment: Please check security group is port 27017 open ?

Comment: Check the screenshots I added in the question. Does it look good ?

Answer (score 3):

Please follow this link in the developer guide[1]. Trying to connect to an Amazon DocumentDB cluster directly from a public endpoint, such as your laptop or local development machine, will fail. Amazon DocumentDB is virtual private cloud (VPC)-only and does not currently support public endpoints. Thus, you can't connect directly to your Amazon DocumentDB cluster from your laptop or local development environment outside of your VPC. You have to setup an EC2 to proxy/ssh tunnel through[2].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/studio3t.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-ec2.html

Comment: i found below aws blog which connects to documentDb via VPN and does not require EC2.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/securely-access-amazon-documentdb-with-mongodb-compatibility-locally-using-aws-client-vpn/

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the below blog of aws you can connect DocumentDb from your Local environment using only VPN no need of any EC2 instance.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/securely-access-amazon-documentdb-with-mongodb-compatibility-locally-using-aws-client-vpn/